# How to convert an Array to a Bindinglist?

Tags: winforms, linq, entity-framework, datagridview, linq-to-entities

- Can you explain me why does this occur in these two different outputs?

[image: Click here to see the image]

- In the description I translated the code to better understand the question
- How can I convert an Array in a IBindingList? Because is imposible sort my DataGridView

Code:

```
public class ProductDALC
{
    public List<Product> ListProducts() //Product is the table name of my Database named DotNetStore
    {
        DotNetDataContext DataModel = new DotNetDataContext();
        var query = from objProduct in DataModel.Product.AsEnumerable()
                  select new Product { idProduct = objProducto.CodProduct, Name = objProduct.Name };

        return query.ToList();    
    }

    public Array ArrayProducts()
    {
        DotNetDataContext DataModel = new DotNetDataContext();
        var query = from objProduct in DataModel.Product.AsEnumerable()
                    select new
                    {     
                        idProduct = ("0000" + Convert.ToString(objProduct.idProduct)).Substring(("0000" + Convert.ToString(objProduct.idProduct)).Length - 4, 4),
                        Nombre = objProduct.Name,
                        Cantidad = objProduct.Quantity

                    };

        return query.ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do you try this:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132681.aspx

```
public BindingList<Product> ArrayProducts()
{
    DotNetDataContext DataModel = new DotNetDataContext();
    var query = from objProduct in DataModel.Product.AsEnumerable()
                select new Product
                {     
                    idProduct = ("0000" + Convert.ToString(objProduct.idProduct)).Substring(("0000" + Convert.ToString(objProduct.idProduct)).Length - 4, 4),
                    Nombre = objProduct.Name,
                    Cantidad = objProduct.Quantity 
                };

    return new BindingList<Customer>(query.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply. This works with the first function(ListProducts) but not from the second function (ArrayProducts). I can not do "BindingList<Product>(query.ToList())" . 
Do you think it is because the function returns an Array or perhaps because the data type of the field "idProduct" is an integer?

Comment: @KevinPerez  It should work if you use `select new Product` for second fucntion

Comment: Thank you again! this works. But this is not an Array to Binging list. However, all your advice has helped me alot to find other ways to solve my problem. Greetings..